# Does Karate offer support for enhancing web application performance using Gatling?

Tags: performance, karate

I have a brief inquiry: Does Karate offer support for enhancing web application performance? I've included a feature file for web application automation within the simulation file, and I'm encountering the error attached herewith.

```
Parsing log file(s)...
...
17:08:24.414 [main] INFO  i.gatling.charts.stats.LogFileReader - First pass
17:08:24.419 [main] INFO  i.gatling.charts.stats.LogFileReader - First pass done: read 5 lines
17:08:24.425 [main] INFO  i.gatling.charts.stats.LogFileReader - Second pass
17:08:24.431 [main] INFO  i.gatling.charts.stats.LogFileReader - Second pass: read 5 lines
Parsing log file(s) done
Generating reports...
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:53)
    at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: There were no requests sent during the simulation, reports won't be generated
    at io.gatling.charts.report.ReportsGenerator.generateFor(ReportsGenerator.scala:50)
    at io.gatling.app.RunResultProcessor.generateReports(RunResultProcessor.scala:65)
    at io.gatling.app.RunResultProcessor.processRunResult(RunResultProcessor.scala:40)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:97)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:49)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:38)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
    ... 6 more
```

I was expecting the report should get generated. Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: you can assume that currently the answer is no, karate-gatling works for api tests